# MySQL Intermediate-Level Table Relationship

Tags: mysql

Each row in Table_1 needs to have a relationship with one or more rows that might come from any number of other tables in the database (Table_X). So I set up an intermediate table (Table_2) where each row contains an id from Table_1, and the id from Table_X. It also has its own auto increment id since none of the relationships will be exclusive and therefore both the other ids will not be unique in the table.

My problem now is that when I retrieve the row from Table_1 and would like to see the information from each related row from Table_X, I don't know how to get it. At first I thought I could create a column for the exact name of Table_X for each row in Table_2 and have a second SELECT statement using that information, but I've been seeing inklings about things such as foreign keys and join statements that I think I need to get into. I'm just having trouble sorting it all out. Do I even need Table_2?

This probably isn't overly complicated, but I'm just getting into MySQL and this is the first real challenge I've encountered.

Edit to include requested information: If I understand correctly, I think I'm dealing with a many to many relationship. Table_3 has games; Table_1 has articles. An article can be about multiple games, and a game can also have multiple articles written about it. The only other possibly pertinent information I can see is that when a new article is made, every game that will be related to it is decided all at once. But the list of articles related to a given game can grow over time as more articles are written. That's probably not especially important, however.

Comment: Let's say you have 3 tables, table A, table B, and table C. If table A can only have one relationship to table B, and to table C, then a simple key based join. If table A can have n matches in table B, and m matches in table C, and table B and C have no relationships, you'd need something of a mapping table. If you can provide details and what you want to accomplish it might help figuring out your data structure needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly You are talking about one to many relationship in database (for example: one person can have multiple phone numbers), You can store data in two separate tables `persons` and `phones`.

Persons:

```
|person_id|person_name  |person_age |
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        |
```

Phones:

```
|phone_id |person_id   |phone_number|
| 1       | 1          | 31337      |
| 2       | 1          | 370        |
```

Then you can execute query with Join:

```
SELLECT * FROM `persons`
  LEFT JOIN `phones` ON `persons`.`person_id` = `phones`.`person_id`
  WHERE `persons`.`person_id` = 1;
```

And it will return to You list of persons with phone numbers:

```
|person_id|person_name  |person_age |phone_id |person_id   |phone_number|
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        | 1       | 1          | 31337      |
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        | 2       | 1          | 370        |
```

Another possibility is Many to Many relationship (for example: Any person can love pizza, and pizza is not unique for that person), then You need third table to join tables together `person_food`

Persons:

```
|person_id|person_name  |person_age |
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        |
```

Food:

```
|food_id |food_name |
| 1      | meat     |
| 2      | pizza    |
```

Person_Food

```
|person_id |food_id |
| 1        | 2      |
```

Then you can execute query with Join:

```
SELLECT * FROM `persons`
  LEFT JOIN `person_food` ON `person`.`person_id` = `person_food`.`person_id`
  LEFT JOIN `food` ON `food`.`food_id` = `person_food`.`food_id`
  WHERE `persons`.`person_id` = 1;
```

And it will return data from all tables:

```
|person_id|person_name  |person_age |person_id |food_id   |food_name |
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        | 1        | 2        | pizza    |
```

However sometimes you need to join `n` amount of tables to join, then You could use separate table to hold information about relation. My approach (I don't think it's the best) would be to store table name next to relation (for example split mobile phones and home phones into two separate tables):

Persons:

```
|person_id|person_name  |person_age |
| 1       | Bodan Kustan| 28        |
```

Mobile_Phone:

```
|mobile_phone_id |mobile_phone_number |
| 1              | 31337              |
```

Home_Phone:

```
|home_phone_id |home_phone_number |
| 1            | 370              |
```

Person_Phone:

```
|person_id |related_id |related_column   |related_table |
| 1        | 1         | mobile_phone_id | mobile_phone |
| 1        | 1         | home_phone_id   | home_phone   |
```

Then query middle table to get all relations:

SELECT * FROM `person_phone` WHERE `person_id` = 1

Then build dynamic query (pseudo code, not tested -- might not work):

```
foreach (results as result)
  append_to_final_sql = "LEFT JOIN {related_table} 
    ON {related_table}.{related_column} = `person_phone`.`related_id`
    AND `person_phone`.`related_table` = {related_table}"
final_sql = "SELECT * FROM `persons` " 
  + append_to_final_sql + 
  " WHERE `persons`.`person_id` = 1"
```

So Your final SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `persons`
  LEFT JOIN `person_phone` ON `person_phone`.`person_id` = `person`.`person_id`
  LEFT JOIN `mobile_phone` ON `mobile_phone`.`mobile_phone_id` = `person_phone`.`related_id` AND `person_phone`.`related_table` = 'mobile_phone'
  LEFT JOIN `home_phone` ON `home_phone`.`home_phone_id` = `person_phone`.`related_id` AND `person_phone`.`related_table` = 'home_phone'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need Table2 if entries in Table_x can be related to multiple rows in Table1 - otherwise a simple key for Table1 will suffice.

Look into joins - very powerful, flexible and fast.

```
select * from Table1 left join Table2 on Table1_id = Table2_table_1_id
left join Table_X on Tablex_id = Table2_table_x_id
```

Look at the output and you'll see that it returns all table_x rows with copies of the Table1 and Table2 fields.